# Is ElYusubov accumulating reputation points at a record pace?

Tags: discussion, reputation, fun

As of the time of this posting, [ElYusubov](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/57164/elyusubov) has been a Programmers.SE member for **59 days.** Yet he has accumulated over 7600 in reputation.

Is this a record pace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  He is not even in the top 20.

http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/revision/77468/88106/reputation-per-day-average-from-highest-to-lowest

The following is a query ranking our top users by Average Reputation Per Day.  Here is the top 20 users by that measure.

> Pierre 303 56
>
> Péter Török 54
>
> S.Lott 53
>
> Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen 46
>
> Robert Harvey 41
>
> FrustratedWithFormsDesigner 40
>
> Mason Wheeler 38
>
> ChrisF 37
>
> Thomas Owens 36
>
> Steven A. Lowe 35
>
> maple_shaft 35
>
> MainMa 35
>
> tdammers 35
>
> Jeff O 33
>
> pdr 33
>
> Jerry Coffin 31
>
> user281377 31
>
> Caleb 30
>
> Oded 30
>
> Anna Lear 29

**UPDATE:**

The Data Explorer tool is not real time production data.  It is a limited subset of a snapshot at a specific point in time.  It looks like the last time the Data Explorer was refreshed was back in July, meaning that it will exclude some of ElYusubov's busiest weeks in his short time here.

To rephrase, he may NOW be in the top 20, but we won't be able to find out until the next Data Explorer update :)

Comment: The rep per day query is interesting, but I see some users there that where earning rep _fast_ when active on the site, but sadly haven't visited for a while.

Comment: @YannisRizos It would be interesting to think of a query that will calculate a ranking on most rep accumulated during a smaller period of time, but that is a different window of time for each person.  Regardless, we can historically see that this breakneck pace just isn't sustainable.  The top user by this measure his Pierre303 and I think he rage quitted a while ago over the direction of the site.

Comment: I don't need a stinkin' explorer to do a simple divide `7600/59 ~= 129` rep per day :)

Comment: Another notable rage quit on here would be S.Lott, I haven't seen him on in a long time.

Comment: @gnat How do you know though that in the past months there were 20 other new users who amassed tons of points?  Thats my point, I highly suspect that he is on the list but we can't know for sure or his ranking without Data Explorer

Comment: Pierre ragequit? What are you talking about, still around, [answering questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159115/should-agile-teams-deliver-new-features-daily/159125#159125), [writing for our blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2012/07/how-we-managed-24-software-development-trainees/), etc...

Comment: @maple_shaft well past months are quite easy to estimate - [Reputation league -> quarter](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=quarter): ElYusubov at top with 6,651, next from top has 3,329... and [yours truly](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat "gnat") not even in top 10, with precious little 1,648. Games people play...

Comment: @YannisRizos That is good to know, but it shows how I haven't seen much activity from him in a while that he is nowhere near as active as his first few months are.  Unless of course if you are [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) and the only thing keeping your heart pumping is a machine that can be powered only by Stack Exchange reputation

Comment: @maple_shaft Somebody leaving the site isn't necessarily a ragequit. The latter is unnecessarily dramatic (and frequently amusing) by definition. Most folks who disagreed with the direction of the site and chose to leave as a result did so fairly quietly, without raging.

Answer (score 4):

While extremely impressive, it's not a record. Our top user, [Pierre 303](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/2567/pierre-303), had amassed 9500+ points his first couple of months, according to his [reputation graph](http://stackexchange.com/users/132549/pierre?tab=reputation). Don't know if that's the record or not, dig around Data Explorer and let us know if you find someone with a faster pace.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usogf.png]

Comment: Cool reputation graph. Now how is it that his rep dropped by several thousand in late 2010? Did he ask a question with that many downvotes, or is this a glitch in the data?

Comment: @StuartMarks Probably a rep recalc. Or a few massive bounties.

Comment: Oh yes, bounties, forgot about that. Thx.

Comment: @YannisRizos recalc is unlikely - the famous one happened earlier than that: ["The global reputation recalc of March 2010"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010)

Comment: Don't forget that alot of those points were prior to the "Great Realignment", when questions and their answers were very different.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was bounties. I remember a roughly 2-week period where Pierre was putting up 500 rep bounties daily

Answer (score 1):

I don't know.

You can use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) to analyse historical data to see how this compares to other users in the past.